# Open source Multiplayer Socket Server for Virtual World

Tags: actionscript-3, socketserver, mmo

Are there any open source multiplayer socket servers that can be used for virtual world development? 
I've been looking at SmartFoxServer & Electroserver, but there very pricey.

Comment: Sorry you haven't gotten any answers yet; come on over to the Game Development Stack Exchange site and perhaps you'll have better luck. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like this: https://github.com/reddwarf-nextgen/reddwarf

Other possible alternatives:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/arianne

http://ryzomcore.org

http://www.photonengine.com